# Create dynamic query for both AND & OR conditions using django

Tags: mysql, django

Basically based on multiple filters selected I have created below JSON.

```
{
    "category1": ["A", "B", "C"],
    "category2": ["x", "y", "z"],
    "category3": ["med1", "med2"]
}
```

**I am looking for below query created dynamically from above JSON**

```
query=((Q(category__name__contains="category1") &
(Q(subcategory__name__contains="A")|  
Q(subcategory__name__contains="B")|Q(subcategory__name__contains="C"))
)|(Q(category__name__contains="category2") &
(Q(subcategory__name__contains="x")| 
Q(subcategory__name__contains="y")|Q(subcategory__name__contains="z"))

)|(Q(category__name__contains="categor3") & 
(Q(subcategory__name__contains="med1")| 
Q(subcategory__name__contains="med2"))
))
```

Product.objects.filter(query)

Any ideas on how to do this? Do I have to use row SQL query or can be done by Django query?

Answer (score 0):

use in:

```
query = (Q(category__name__contains="category1") &
         Q(subcategory__name__in=json['category1'])) |
        (Q(category__name__contains="category2") &
         Q(subcategory__name__in=json['category2'])) |
        (Q(category__name__contains="categor3") & 
         Q(subcategory__name__in=json['categor3']))
```